# Splitting an N digit integer into M number of pieces

Tags: python

I am tying to write a code in python which lists all possible permutations when you split an N digit integer into M number of pieces for eg:-235654 is a 6 digit number. Here n=6. Let m=6, then the only possible permutation is 2,3,5,6,5,4. If m=3 then there would be 10 possible permutations like 2,3,5654  23,56,54  235,6,54....etc. You can easily calculate the total number of such permutations by adding all the possible ways in which you place two commas between the digits. In this case it is 5!/2!3!. But writing a code to list all the permutations seems very difficult. Can somebody write a program or algorithm to list all possible permutation when we try to split a 5 digit number like 12345 into 3 pieces for eg:-1,2,345 and 12,34,5. Right now I can only divide the number into 2 pieces using the following code.

```
c=[1,2,3,4,5]
l=len(c)
i1=0
a=[]
b=[]
while i1<l-1:
    i2=0
    while i2<=i1:
        a.append(c[i2])
        i2=i2+1
    i1=i1+1
    while i2<l:
        b.append(c[i2])
        i2=i2+1
    print(f"{a} {b}")
    a=[]
    b=[]
```

Comment: Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=permute#itertools.permutations out

Comment: `itertools.combinations(range(1, len(c)), m - 1)` will give you all possible index combinations to split on to get your results

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=permute#itertools.combinations) to find all possible indices where you can split the string:

```
from itertools import combinations


def all_splits(s, num):
    perms = [[0] + list(i) + [len(s)] for i in list(combinations(range(1, len(s)), num - 1))]
    return [[s[indices[i]: indices[i + 1]] for i in range(len(indices) - 1)] for indices in perms]


print(all_splits("abcdef", 6))
# Output: [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]

print(all_splits("abcdef", 3))
# Output: [['a', 'b', 'cdef'], ['a', 'bc', 'def'], ['a', 'bcd', 'ef'], ['a', 'bcde', 'f'], ['ab', 'c', 'def'],
#          ['ab', 'cd', 'ef'], ['ab', 'cde', 'f'], ['abc', 'd', 'ef'], ['abc', 'de', 'f'], ['abcd', 'e', 'f']]

print(all_splits("abcdef", 1))
# Output: [['abcdef']]
```